Where is the tunnable part of Spike Neural Network?
SNN closely mimic the Biological Neural Network. The dataset dims always (Num of Sample, Features, Num of Timestep), even the dataset is not time-dependent, it's still containing time dimension.
So, where is the tunnable part of SNN?
Suppose this concrete example, Classification of Adolescence based on Weight and Height, with total 3 people.
Here, the X_data has shape (3, 2, 1), correct? no?
And the target is simply binary number.
But, where is the tunnable part of SNN? Aka the weights? What is the simplified of learning process in SNN? Is there concept of forward propagation and backward propagation too? like Artificial Neural Network? How the model decide it? What is the interpretability of SNN, compared to Deep Neural Network from ANN?
